# C 64bit compilation on VS Code with Windows 10

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, 64-bit

I can't compile a 64 bit c code on visual studio code with Windows 10. It seems to compile always in 32bit since I get `sizeof(unsigned long)` = 4.

I have mingw-64 compiler and for `gcc --version` I get on he integrated terminal (I am using PowerShell v1.0):

`gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0 Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

So I do not understand why I always have a 32 bit executable. With the same computer with Pop!Os(Ubuntu) I get `sizeof(unsigned long)` = 8 so I can compile with 64bit on Linux but no on Windows 10. And I have the same problem on my two computers.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: On Windows, `sizeof(unsigned long)` is 4 even in 64 bit mode. Try `sizeof(void*)` or `sizeof(size_t)`.

Comment: Ok thank, `sizeof(size_t) = 8` and `sizeod(void*) = 8` too. and VS Code says that size_t is typedef of `unsigned long long` on Windows or in linux size_t is typedef of `unsigned long`. How to have the same result without change `unsigned long` by `unsigned long long`? (with size_t ?)

Comment: If you need a 64 bit integer type, use `int64_t`. If you need a type large enough to hold a size, use `size_t`. There is no good reason to use `long` in user code. You cannot make `long` 64 bits on Windows because the ABI says it must be 32 bits.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your hepl. But I do not understand why Windows and linux don't use the same value for long